# How to search columns in search input only from logged-in user data?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How will I get only the columns of the logged user on input search query? Means that I search only the data that he has stored

```
$restaurants = Restaurant::where('title', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
```

Restaurant have user_id column, in user model:

```
public function restaurants() { 
    return $this->hasMany('App\Restaurant'); 
}
```

in restaurant model:

```
public function user() { 
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); 
}
```

Comment: How restaurants and users are connected? Attach models or table schemas.

Comment: @IndianCoding Restaurant have user_id column, 
in user model:
`public function restaurants() {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Restaurant');
 }`
in restaurant model:
`public function user() {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }`

Comment: Add schemas to the post @Kingpin

Comment: sorry i not did your last comment but its works nou, thanks mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
$user = \Auth::user();
$restaurants = Restaurant::where('title', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                         ->where("user_id", $user->id)
                         ->get();
```

If you would like to add it globaly scoped Restorent model you should use **Global Scope**.

With this solution, you just need to add a **Global Scope** with Restorent model and after that for each restorent related transaction user could fetch/update/delete their own entries only.

**App/Scopes/UserScope.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Scopes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class UserScope implements Scope
{
    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $builder->where('user_id', \Auth::user()->id);
    }
}
```

Ueses: in your model **Restaurant.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Scopes\UserScope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Restaurant extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(new UserScope);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good story but I'll do this later if I need it.

Comment: `$restaurants = Restaurant::where('title', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')->where("user_id", \Auth::user()->id);` try this.

Comment: @Kingpin updated this in ans as well. please confirm does this work for you.

Comment: @Kingpin You are welcome! please do accept the ans. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You can get current user with Auth Facade :

```
    $currentUser = \Auth::user();//Get current User Model
    $restaurants = Restaurant::where([
    ['user_id','=',$currentUser->id],
    ['title', 'like', '%'.$query.'%']
])->get();
```

Not tested,
Hope this helps

**Edit : Tested Now**

You should use get() method or ( alternates to get() rows that match your conditions .

Comment: I finished it and working perfectly, thanks on your time

Answer (score 0):

Since you have relations you can write the code like this

```
$user = Auth::user();
if ($user) {
    $restaurants = $user->restaurants()->where('title', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')->get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, simple solution but how to add another _orWhere_ in $restaurants variable? I want to say from the description to search?

Comment: You can chain all the where you want: `$restaurants = $user->restaurants()->where('title', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')->orWhere('yourField', 'yourvalue')->get();`

Comment: I tried that way but I got it all back, it must be for every _where_ specifically defined user_id, but I did that and works, thanks

Comment: If you use `$user->restaurants()` you will then filter only on restaurants where user_id = your user.

Glad it helped, though!